# pandas float64 DataFrame column not behaving like one (wrt describe and to_csv functions)

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am trying to export a pandas (v0.19.2) DataFrame - coming from read_excel and some manipulations - to a CSV file.

While some columns are recognised as float64, neither the describe method nor the float formatting in the to_csv function work... (They do work perfectly with randomly generated data though).

Basically, the line

```
df["my_column"].describe()
```

returns this:

```
count     5.0
unique    5.0
top       7.0
freq      1.0
Name: my_column, dtype: float64
```

while I would expect it to return something like this

```
count    6.000000
mean     0.276880
std      1.032943
min     -1.542513
25%     -0.103334
50%      0.797131
75%      0.896404
max      1.083524
Name: my_column, dtype: float64
```

Same for exporting to a CSV file:

```
df["my_column"].to_csv("test.csv", sep=';', decimal=',', float_format="%.2f")
```

creates the following file:

```
0;220
1;154
2;7
3;140.800003051758
4;48.4000015258789
```

while I would expect:

```
0;220,00
1;154,00
2;7,00
3;140,80
4;48,40
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Maybe need convert to `float` first - `df["my_column"].astype(float).to_csv("test.csv", sep=';', decimal=',', float_format="%.2f")`

Comment: Great! It worked (for `.describe()` as well)! I do not really understand why though, since pandas was already telling me it was a `float`, but thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need convert to `float` first by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html), because it seems some values are strings and some numeric:

```
df["my_column"].astype(float).to_csv("test.csv", sep=';', decimal=',', float_format="%.2f")
```

Comment: Great! It worked (for `.describe()` as well)! I do not really understand why though, since pandas was already telling me it was a `float`, but thanks!